# Python conversion error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

Trying to get an LCD 20x4 working.
But I get an error:

Error Message = "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'."

This is the line that throws the error:

```
       string = " " * (LCD_WIDTH / 2 - len(string) / 2) + string + " " * ((LCD_WIDTH - 1) / 2 - len(string) / 2)
```

It should center the text on the LCD.
This is the full code:

```
   def lcd_display_string(self, string, line, mode = 1):
    if line == 1:
        self.lcd_write(0x80)
    if line == 2:
        self.lcd_write(0xC0)
    if line == 3:
        self.lcd_write(0x94)
    if line == 4:
        self.lcd_write(0xD4)

    if mode == 0: # left alignment
        string = string + " " * (LCD_WIDTH - len(string))
    if mode == 1: # centered
        string = " " * (LCD_WIDTH / 2 - len(string) / 2) + string + " " * ((LCD_WIDTH - 1) / 2 - len(string) / 2)
    if mode == 2: # right alignment
        string = " " * (LCD_WIDTH - len(string)) + string

    for char in string:
        self.lcd_write(ord(char), Rs)
```

Mode 0 and 2 are OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is properly identified: the expression

```
" " * ((LCD_WIDTH - 1) / 2 - len(string) / 2)
```

is invalid, as the number on the right is a float.  Simply use integer arithmetic.

```
" " * ((LCD_WIDTH - 1) // 2 - len(string) // 2)
```

Comment: Good to know.  This is included in a lot of tutorials, but isn't as straightforward to look up as many other concepts.  BTW, don't forget to choose a best answer, so you get a few points refunded, and the question gets properly archived.